# A word for a small unimportant component upon which the whole depends and that breaks easily?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In my language we have a slang word for a small part of the whole that is not very significant for the functionality of the whole but which breaks easily and in such case renders the whole useless.

Manufacturers are often suspected of including such a part intentionally to shorten the lifespan of a product after the guarantee expires. Is there such word in English?

Comment: Such small part is the "*Achilles 'heel*" of the system. But, this expression don't specifically refer to planned obsolescence.

Comment: This is very close, but Achilles heel conveys the unintentional nature of the weakness which is just an unfortunate coincidence. The word I'm looking for has a strongly negative meaning because of intention or incompetence.

Comment: If the whole depends on it then it's not "unimportant".

Comment: Perhaps "deliberate weak point", but a fuse is a "deliberate weak spot" put in the system so that the weak spot blows instead of the cabling.

Comment: What is the word in your language?

Comment: ***Intentional flaws*** (or its variants), I believe.

Comment: Related but not synonymous is 'planned obsolescence'.

Comment: @Mitch that is a great suggestion. http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/planned_obsolescence.asp

Comment: Planned obsolescence refers to the whole product, and the planned failure can take different forms. In this case, the OP is talking about the *weak link* that initiates breakdown and thus obsolescence.

Comment: Another related but not synonymous term: 'single point of failure'.

Comment: It might help if you told us the source word and language that you want translated.

Comment: Yes, please, give us the original.  *Critical component* partially gets to your idea, but we also need a little more, such as *weak link*, plus the intentionality of it.  I want to learn your word for it.

Comment: The word in Czech language is "kurvítko" and it is used with this meaning among engineers. It's a bit vulgar and ambiguous, so it can have other meaning for another groups of people.

Answer (score 1):

***Intentional flaws*** (or variations of the phrase) can be seen used by many articles online.

There's also a related one called ***Persian flaw*** — [Wikia](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Persian_flaw)

> A Persian flaw, was a flaw intentionally introduced by Persian artisans of Earth to signify that man was inherently flawed. The expression "Persian flaw" might also be used figuratively.

Comment: I really like the Persian flaw term. It's however very positive, a sign of humility instead of incompetence. But I think it's as close as we I can get, thanks.